# Making Amazon Echo / Alexa work outside of US, UK, Germany and Canada

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo

According to [Amazon Echo's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Echo), they're only available in the US, UK, Germany and Canada.

> Echo's Achilles heel is Amazon's unwillingness to look beyond the US. - [The Australian](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/life/personal-technology/amazon-echos-alexa-miles-ahead-of-apples-siri-on-commands/news-story/98190fae503dfd5fab077145a987df23)

However, being primarily an IoT device, they should work where ever they can get power and internet access.

**Can they work outside the countries listed above?**

I'm in *[Australia](https://www.finder.com.au/amazon-alexa-echo-dot-australia)* and wanted to know if it can work.

If yes, are any features or services lost?

Answer (score 19):

## TLDR: YES

**Yes, Amazon Echo will work outside of the supported countries**, but some functionality will be lost.

---

**Power**

Amazon Echo supports 110-220 volts which means it works across the whole world without a voltage converter.

**Plug**

The Plug is localised to where ever you're buying it.

[image: Americano power]

I had to buy an adapter.

**App**

Amazon Echo *requires* a companion App. But this isn't available in all areas. You'll have to jailbreak your iPhone or use an Android to install the app from the web.

The Android version is available: [APK Mirror has a version](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/amazon-mobile-llc/amazon-alexa/echo-1-5-16-release/amazon-echo-1-5-16-android-apk-download/)

**Services**

Location based services won't work. The app expects an American 5-digit postcode. That means anything that requires your location might* not work. 
This applies to core features:

- Local news
- Movie times
- Traffic
- Weather

This applies to skills as well, e.g.

- Uber
- Lyft
- TV guide
- Dominos

* See Below

---

**What does work?**

**Core** - Amazon itself works as long as it has power and internet.

**Smart home** - All the smart home devices that would otherwise work in your country work.

**Time zones** - You can set your timezone to anywhere in the world.

**Music** - It can play music if you would otherwise be able to play it, e.g. Amazon Play, Pandora & Spotify all work for me.

**Weather** - It can get weather for most cities in the world, but you must ask about your city. e.g. "*Alexa, what is the weather in Cairo, Egypt?*"

**More Skills** - All the skills that don't require your location have worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the Amazon Echo will fine at your location. The one big difference is going to be in the Skills. Some skills have location specific data attached to them which will make them not work properly in certain locations.